# measurability condition

Tags: measure-theory

> A set $A \subset X$ is $\mu$ measurable if 
>   \begin{equation}
> \mu(E)=\mu(E \cap A)+ \mu(E \setminus A) \text{ for all $E \subset X$} 
> \end{equation}

Does this work equally well for $\mu$ an outer measure and $\mu$ a measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an outer measure $\mu^*$, you'll have $\mu^*(E) \leq \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^* ( E - A)$ for all $E \in 2^X$.

However, if you restrict the sets to which that's an equality, the outer measure becomes a measure.

By countable additivity for a measure, the statement holds true for any measure.